# Elements in a webdriver reference variable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I print my Webdriver reference variable, I get the following value,

```
ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (d4631482441c5b7fd464863f70aba801)
```

Can someone explain in detail about what these values mean **individually**?

Answer (score 0):

Once the *ChromeDriver* successfully  instantiates a *Chrome Browsing Context*, if you print the the instance of the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) variant i.e. the *ChromeDriver*:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();
System.out.println(driver);
```

The console output is:

```
ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (34992f3b864a9063bf5fe90e4e09345e)
```

---

### Explanation

The components of the output are as follows:

- `ChromeDriver`: Represents the *WebDriver* variant.
- `WINDOWS`: Represents the *Platform* variant.
- `34992f3b864a9063bf5fe90e4e09345e`: Represents the *SessionID* of the *Browsing Context*.

Comment: What dies the value (34992f3b864a9063bf5fe90e4e09345e) mean?

Comment: @SanjayNitin Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Now I understand the meaning, but I am facing a null pointer exception in the framework I am using. The first class runs fine but before the execution of the second class, it throws null pointer exception.

If you have a little time can you look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189394/issue-in-selenium-testng-page-object-model-framework

Answer (score 0):

You see the `toString()` of `RemoteWebDriver`, which `ChromeDriver` inherits from. `ChromeDriver` doesn't override it so you see the parent implementation

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s: %s on %s (%s)", getClass().getSimpleName(), caps.getBrowserName(), platform, getSessionId());
}
```

`getClass().getSimpleName()` = ChromeDriver

`caps.getBrowserName()` = Chrome

`platform` = Windoes XP

`getSessionId()` = d4631482441c5b7fd464863f70aba801